# Python Mocking a function from an imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I want to understand how to `@patch` a function from an imported module.

This is where I am so far.

**app/mocking.py:**

```
from app.my_module import get_user_name

def test_method():
  return get_user_name()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print "Starting Program..."
  test_method()
```

**app/my_module/__init__.py:**

```
def get_user_name():
  return "Unmocked User"
```

**test/mock-test.py:**

```
import unittest
from app.mocking import test_method 

def mock_get_user():
  return "Mocked This Silly"

@patch('app.my_module.get_user_name')
class MockingTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_mock_stubs(self, mock_method):
    mock_method.return_value = 'Mocked This Silly')
    ret = test_method()
    self.assertEqual(ret, 'Mocked This Silly')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

This does **not** work as I would expect. The "patched" module simply returns the unmocked value of `get_user_name`. How do I mock methods from other packages that I am importing into a namespace under test?

Comment: I am asking if I am going about this right. I looked at Mock, but I don't see a way to solve this particular problem. Is there a way to recreate what I did above in Mock?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

When you are using the `patch` decorator from the `unittest.mock` package you are **patching it in the namespace that is under test** (in this case `app.mocking.get_user_name`), not the namespace the function is imported from (in this case `app.my_module.get_user_name`).

To do what you describe with `@patch` try something like the below:

```
from mock import patch
from app.mocking import test_method 

class MockingTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @patch('app.mocking.get_user_name')
    def test_mock_stubs(self, test_patch):
        test_patch.return_value = 'Mocked This Silly'
        ret = test_method()
        self.assertEqual(ret, 'Mocked This Silly')
```

The standard library documentation includes a useful [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) describing this.

Comment: this gets to my problem. `get_user_name` is in a different module than `test_method`. Is there a way to mock something in a sub_module? I fixed it in an ugly way below.

Comment: It doesn't matter that `get_user_name` is in a different module than `test_method` since you are importing the function into `app.mocking` they are in the same namespace.

Comment: Where did test_patch come from, what is it exactly?

Comment: test_patch is passed in by the patch decorator and is the mocked get_user_name object (i.e. an instance of the MagicMock class). It might be clearer if it was named something like `get_user_name_patch`.

Comment: How are you referencing test_method? It will result in error, NameError: global name 'test_method' is not defined

Comment: `test_method` is just a placeholder for the function being tested, in the question it's imported. I have added the import to match the example code in the question.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. It had me thrown for a while that you only need to stub the imported callable

Comment: I think this section should be moved on the very top of the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much! Despite having read the "Where to patch" section of the docs, I didn't fully grok it until I read your answer.

Comment: One little caveat that I tripped over just now was that the "from mock import patch" line *must* be the first line. If you import test_method first, and then import patch, it won't work. Just wanted to highlight that.

Answer (score 26):

While Matti John's answer solves your issue (and helped me too, thanks!), I would, however, suggest localizing the replacement of the original 'get_user_name' function with the mocked one. This will allow you to control when the function is replaced and when it isn't. Also, this will allow you to make several replacements in the same test. In order to do so, use the 'with' statment in a pretty simillar manner:

```
from mock import patch

class MockingTestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_mock_stubs(self):
        with patch('app.mocking.get_user_name', return_value = 'Mocked This Silly'):
            ret = test_method()
            self.assertEqual(ret, 'Mocked This Silly')
```

Comment: This is sort of immaterial to the posed question. Whether you use `patch` as a decorator or context manager is specific to the use case.  For instance you can use `patch` as a decorator to mock a value for all tests in an `xunit` or `pytest` class while in other cases its useful to have the fine grained control afforded by the context manager.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is correct that using `patch` you have to consider the namespace in which it is imported. But imagine that you'd want to override the *actual* implementation on a global basis no matter where it is imported you can `monkeypatch` the implementation:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def get_user_name_mock(monkeypatch):
    _mock = MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr(app.my_module, app.my_module.get_user_name.__name__, _mock )
    return _mock
```

In your tests, just add the name of the fixture as an argument like default fixture behavior.

In my projects I use this to override my global config value resolvement to catch *unmocked* `config.get` calls which could cause undefined behavior.

edit: link to docs: https://pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#how-to-monkeypatch-mock-modules-and-environments

Answer (score -3):

Besides Matti John's solution, you can also import module instead of function in `app/mocking.py`.

```
# from app.my_module import get_user_name
from app import my_module

def test_method():
  return my_module.get_user_name()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print "Starting Program..."
  test_method()
```

Comment: Why does this get downvoted? Changing the way things get imported has its disadvantages but I can think of many scenarios in which this might actually be better than patching at importing modules.

Comment: I think it's not clear how this answers the question. This is just a semantic alternative for addressing the function. At the heart of the question was "Why does this mock not work as expected?" your answer doesn't answer that question.