# Python patch not working, no calls being recorded

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-3.x, magicmock

First time working with MagicMock, and I think I've confused myself.

Testing a django project, so in a file called `services.py` I have these important elements (extremely simplified and with many bits cut out, of course)::

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

class Email:
    def send_success_attempt_email(self):
        template = get_template('emails/foo.html')
```

I want to test that when `send_success_attempt_email` gets called, `get_template` gets called with the correct arguments. So I wrote a test with a patch:

```
@patch('django.template.loader.get_template')
def test_email_template_should_be_used(self, get_template):
    email = Email()
    email.send_success_attempt_email()
    print(get_template.call_count)
    get_template.assert_called_with('emails/foo.html')
```

Which prints `0` for the `call_count`, and spits out the

```
AssertionError nose.proxy.AssertionError: 
Expected call: get_template('emails/foo.html')
Not called
```

I've seen that a common pitfall is to patch the wrong instance, but I have tried many variations on the patch (for instance, `@patch('services.get_template')`) but while that changes the error (`nose.proxy.EncodeError: Can't pickle <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>: it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock`), it does not alleviate it.

I know I must have a fundamental misunderstanding. What is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Mocking a method from an imported module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134281/python-mocking-a-method-from-an-imported-module)

Comment: I agree, it could be a duplicate, but looking at the answers of that question, I would expect `@patch('services.get_template')` to work, but it throws the strange error which I have edited into my questions to highlight the oddness.

Comment: Nope, that second error isn't actually related to the patch being incorrect, it is something else. The error message threw me because I thought I was just still constructing the patch wrong.

Comment: Try patching `...services.get_template` instead as services might be loaded before you patch and has kept the original `get_template` reference before you patch it