# How to mock/intercept external API calls during unit(api) testing?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-requests

I need to write a unit test case for my Django server, where I have the structure like following code snippet. This is just a pseudo-code because I just want to get the idea about the approach.

```
# views.py
class UserView(ViewSet):

    def get_info_from_multiple_sources(self, request):
        # assume url for this action is /users/:id/info
        user_id = get_parameters(request)
        info = info_service.get_info(user_id)
        return Response(info)

# user_info_service.py
class UserInfoService:

    def get_info(user_id):
        user_fb_info = fb_service.get_user_info(user_id)
        user_twitter_info = twitter_service.get_user_info(user_id)
        merged_info = merge_info(user_fb_info, user_twitter_info)
        return merged_info

# fb_service.py
class FbService:

    def _manipulate_data(response):
        user_info = None
        # do some processing here, to convert data from fb format to 
        # project format. Assign formatted response to user_info variable.
        return user_info

    def get_user_info(user_id):
        # lets say this imaginary urls gives user info somehow magically.
        response = requests.request('http://fb.com/users/{0}'.format(user_id))
        return self._manipulate_data(response)

# twitter_Service.py
class TwitterService:

    def _manipulate_data(response):
        user_info = None
        # do some processing here, to convert data from twitter format to 
        # project format. Assign formatted response to user_info variable.
        return user_info

    def get_user_info(user_id):
        response  = requests.request('http://twitter.com/users/{0}'.format(user_id))
        return self._manipulate_data(response)

# test_user_info_endpoint.py
class TestUserInfoViewEndpoint(APITestCase):

    def test_user_info(self):
        # how to write a unit test function where
        # I will be mocking only requests.request call. i.e outgoing call to external APIs
```

I am using `unittests` framework, and I am open to using any standard library for it.

Comment: what about monkey-patching requests.request to return a response similar to that of the api you're calling

Comment: @m0etaz How? Can you provide small pseudo-code

Comment: have a look at this library https://pypi.org/project/requests-staticmock/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unittest Django: Mock external API, what is proper way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157543/unittest-django-mock-external-api-what-is-proper-way)