# pytest patch generate exception for Class method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am testing the generating mock exception using `side_effect`. based on this page https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/ I am trying to generate the exception when calling `load_data` method, but its not working for me.

```
test_load_data.py::test_slow_load_02 FAILED                              [100%]
tests/pytest_samples/test_load_data.py:31 (test_slow_load_02)
ds_mock = <MagicMock name='DataSet' id='4473855648'>

    @patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet")
    def test_slow_load_02(ds_mock):
        with patch.object(ds_mock, 'load_data', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
>           with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'Exception'>

test_load_data.py:35: Failed
```

Here is the code.

slow.py

```
class DataSet:

    def load_data(self):
        return 'Loading Data'
```

load_data.py

```
from python_tools.pytest_samples.slow import DataSet


def slow_load():
    dataset = DataSet()
    return dataset.load_data()
```

test_data.py

```
@patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet")
def test_slow_load_02(ds_mock):
    with patch.object(ds_mock, 'load_data', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            actual = slow_load()
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

This test code worked for me:

```
def test_slow_load_01(mocker):
    with mocker.patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet.load_data", side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            actual = slow_load()
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

I like to understand why patch and patch.object is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unit tests - mocking imported modules / functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019865/python-unit-tests-mocking-imported-modules-functions)

Comment: It does with `@patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet.load_data", side_effect=Exception('URLError'))`. Can you update your question to show your changed code?

Comment: @aaron found the answer, posted the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This test code worked for me.

```
import pytest
from python_tools.pytest_samples import load_data

def test_slow_load_02():
    with patch.object(load_data.DataSet, 'load_data', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            actual = load_data.slow_load()
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

Comment: This isn't much different from `@patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet.load_data", side_effect=Exception('URLError'))` as alluded to in the duplicate target.

Comment: I think we should us `patch.object` in this case not `patch`.   patch: replaces the object in the code being tested.
patch.object: replaces an attribute of an object in the code being tested.

Comment: The attribute of an object is an object too. You're patching the exact same thing here -- the method `load_data`.

Answer (score -1):

You are patching the wrong thing; `slow_load` doesn't refer to the class using the expression `python_tools.pytest_samples.slow.DataSet`; it uses the global variable `DataSet`.

```
@patch('load_data.DataSet')
def test_slow_load_02(ds_mock):
    with patch.object(ds_mock, 'load_data', side_effect=Exception('URLError')):
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
            actual = slow_load()
        assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

You don't need `patch.object`; `ds_mock.load_data` is already a mock that you can configure directly.

```
@patch('load_data.DataSet')
def test_slow_load_02(ds_mock):
    ds_mock.load_data.side_effect = Exception('URLError')
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
        actual = slow_load()
    assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'
```

Comment: I tried this `@patch("python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet")
def test_slow_load_02(ds_mock):
    ds_mock.load_data.side_effect = Exception('URLError')
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
        actual = slow_load()
    assert str(excinfo.value) == 'URLError'` still getting the same error message.  unsure what I am missing.

Comment: You didn't change the call to `@patch` like I suggested. It's `load_data.DataSet` you need to patch, not the `python_tools...` name.

Comment: when I use `@patch('load_data.DataSet')` decorator I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'load_data'` error.  in my project my module name is `python_tool` and source file is in `pytest_sample` folder.  so I need to use the full name `python_tools.pytest_samples.load_data.DataSet`.

Comment: I assume you are writing something like `from load_data import slow_load` so that you can call the function. Just add `import load_data` so that that module itself is bound to a name in the scope.

Comment: yes I am using this import `from load_data import slow_load`. most of my application written like this only. do you know why test case its not working with this improt?

Comment: Because, as you've seen, you never define the name `load_data` so you can't patch it.

Comment: if you look at `test_slow_load_01` test case. I was able to mock the `load_data` method using `mocker`.  its not working only with `patch`.