# Test that a function imported into different namespaces is never called

Tags: python, testing, mocking

Suppose I have

foo.py

```
def my_func():
    print('hello world!')
```

bar.py

```
from foo import my_func
```

I want to write tests to ensure that `my_func` is never called.  I have this:

```
from unittest import mock

import foo
import bar

@mock.patch.object(foo, 'my_func', wraps=foo.my_func)
class TestMyFunc:
    def test_from_foo(self, wrapped_my_func):
        foo.my_func()
        wrapped_my_func.assert_not_called()
        
    def test_from_bar(self, wrapped_my_func):
        bar.my_func()
        wrapped_my_func.assert_not_called()
```

Written this way, I would like both tests to fail.  However, run with `pytest`, `test_from_bar` passes.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134281/python-mocking-a-function-from-an-imported-module) I gather that that is because `mock` works on the name spaces so does not know that `foo.my_func` and `bar.my_func` are the same thing.  So is there a way I can write this test without writing patches and asserts for both modules?

**Edit**: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637961/3501128) I was hoping I could combine `mock` with `monkeypatch` to get what I want, but this version of `test_from_bar` still passes:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import pytest

import foo
import bar

class TestMyFunc:
    @pytest.fixture
    def mock_my_func(self, monkeypatch):
        _mock = MagicMock(wraps=foo.my_func)
        monkeypatch.setattr(foo, foo.my_func.__name__, _mock)
        return _mock 

    def test_from_foo(self, mock_my_func):
        foo.my_func()
        mock_my_func.assert_not_called()
        
    def test_from_bar(self, mock_my_func):
        bar.my_func()
        mock_my_func.assert_not_called()
```

##### Context

My real use-case is to test a function that uses [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/index.html).  I want to make sure that [dask.base.compute](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/3e9ae492934e133547e5eaec5020186fad39898a/dask/base.py#L603) is never inadvertently called.  However it may be called as [dask.compute](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/3e9ae492934e133547e5eaec5020186fad39898a/dask/__init__.py#L7) or [dask.array.compute](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/3e9ae492934e133547e5eaec5020186fad39898a/dask/array/__init__.py#L264C34-L264C34) or possibly others that I haven't stumbled on yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Mocking a function from an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134281/python-mocking-a-function-from-an-imported-module)

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, that question explains *why* my current approach does not work.  The accepted answer points out that OP needs to patch the other module.  In my case, I want to assert that is has not been called by any of the possible modules: "is there a way I can write this test without writing patches and asserts for both modules?"  Perhaps the answer is simply "no"...

Comment: Well, technically you could move that `import bar` into the `test_from_bar` method and you'll see that both tests then fail. The issue basically is that `bar` is already imported and hence already has a reference to `my_func`. If you can delay that import until the mock has already happened things will work. Otherwise not so much.

Comment: If anyone is interested, in the real use-case I added a fixture that [patches all known instances of the function with a single `Mock` object](https://github.com/SciTools/iris/blob/fe46e05ca4e972e12a1a5aa42096130341de6d79/lib/iris/tests/unit/analysis/stats/test_pearsonr.py#L44-L55).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AbdulAzizBarkat for pointing out that import order matters!  This does work:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest

import foo

mock_my_func = mock.Mock(wraps=foo.my_func)
pytest.MonkeyPatch().setattr(foo, foo.my_func.__name__, mock_my_func)

import bar

class TestMyFunc:
    def test_from_foo(self):
        foo.my_func()
        mock_my_func.assert_not_called()
        
    def test_from_bar(self):
        bar.my_func()
        mock_my_func.assert_not_called()
    
    def teardown_method(self):
        mock_my_func.reset_mock()
```